# Hide and show Jquery UI tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, hide, show

I am using jquery UI tabs and working pretty well and now I want to hide and show tabs with a click of button as shown below.

On each tab I have a button and when I click it it should hide the present tab and the rest tabs and should show me the next tab.(ie..If I am on tab-1 and If I click button it should show me the tab-2 and should hide 1,3 and 4 tabs) and similarly for 2,3,4 tabs.

This is what I mean ?

[image]

So how do I do that?

Here is my code:
script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #tabs { width: 700px; }
  </style>
```

Tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">TAB1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">TAB2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">TAB3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">TAB4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am working with hidde and show tabs and I applied this solutions. [Adding and remove tabs](http://remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/adding-and-removing-tabs-with-jquery-and-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem here http://beta.kilbot.com.au/labs/jquery/add-remove-tabs-using-jquery/

Comment: Please would you mind to provide the actual solution and not simply a link to it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following snippet of code should do what you want.

```
$("#button_id").click(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs('select', 'tab_index');
});
```

Tab_index should be an integer, it specifies the position of the tab (starting at zero!), so here you would pass in the position of the next or previous tab.
You can [retrieve the current tab index](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#...retrieve_the_index_of_the_currently_selected_tab) as follows:

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
```

I suggest you have a look at the documentation of the [.tabs() select method](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#method-select).

Answer (score -4):

jQuery UI on there site says the correct jQuery syntax for this is to have

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I knew that without that it dosen't wotk and I want it to show and hide.

Comment: Than you are going to have to make a custom functions